# Is there single name for Web Design, Web Development and Web Based Software Development?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

We can use "Digital marketing" or "Online Marketing" word to use instead of `SEO + Social Meia Marketing + Google Adword + Facebook Ads` etc.

Like that, Is there any single name we can use instead of Web Design, Web Development and Web Based Software Development?

Comment: The second strikes me as a perfectly fine hypernym for all three. That said, these terms are not very clearly defined in the first place. Arguably they are also three, or at least two and a half, fundamentally different things. Like looking for a hypernym for *ballet dancer*, *costume designer*, and *conductor* just because they all work in a theater. It's not that it's impossible, it's that it would have to be too broad to be of any use (like *profession*, *craft*, or *thing*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Web Development = Web Design + Web Based Software Development

This is based on my personal experience in the field, not a dictionary definition.

**Web Design** puts the stress on *design*, i.e. the visual aspect of creating a website.

**Web Based Software Development** puts the stress on *software*, i.e. the underlying application that serves the website.

**Web Development** is a more generic term that contains both; since it does not stress the aesthetic or technical nature of the field. It entails the development of a website, which both contains the application that serves it (if applicable) and the design of the website that is served (if applicable).

Comment: I accepted the answer, But I was looking for a word which can give more priority for  Web Based Software Development. But seems like there is no word for it. So I will use web development.

Comment: @DamithRuwan - Well, how about Web Software?  The *based* and the *development* would be understood, I think.

Comment: @DamithRuwan: "Web Application" (or "Web App", which in my opinion suggests a _small_ application) is becoming increasingly populer.

Answer (score 1):

"Full Stack" developer is the phrase you're looking for.  This is an umbrella term for someone who can develop APIs, middle-ware, web pages (including elements of design) and interact/modify the Database.

Comment: I believe they were looking for a noun describing the "product" of development, not the person developing the "product."

Answer (score -3):

A single name "Digital Marketing" can be used for all the field like web design, web development etc.

Comment: Speaking as someone in web development, “digital marketing” doesn't describe our fields. It describes something our fields might be *used* to do, but only some kinds of work in our field has anything to do with marketing.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes, it's a bit like referring to all printing as advertising.